# Wrong duplicate answer was deleted – can this be reversed?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-answer, duplicate-answers

I've just had an answer deleted because it's a duplicate (fair cop / my bad).

Unfortunately, the mod has deleted the answer on the older question, and kept the answer on the newer question. Can someone please reverse this, as I'd like to close the newer question as a duplicate of the older question?

I.e.:

1. UNDELETE → [Code to list all the entries in jndi on remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324937/code-to-list-all-the-entries-in-jndi-on-remote-machine/37021007?noredirect=1#comment61639769_37021007)
2. DELETE → [Is it possible to get "everything" from javax.naming.InitialContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053519/is-it-possible-to-get-everything-from-javax-naming-initialcontext/37019732#37019732) (or I could do this...)

Comment: Why didn't you mod flag the one that wasn't deleted and ask?

Comment: Just an FYI it doesn't matter which questions is oldest.  The dupe target should be the one with the best answers.

Comment: @NathanOliver The mod deleted the answer on the open question and left the answer on the closed as duplicate question...so it really should be the other way around.

Comment: @Machavity thanks - just flagged it for moderator intervention (didn't know I could do that) - want to add it as an answer, or should I just delete this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Mod flag the undeleted answer and explain in detail what you want. They should be able to fix you up.